# OAuth login page redirecting to source org

Tags: oauth2, authentication, authorization

I am using OAuth web server flow to authenticate one salesforce org(source) with another(it can be any other salesforce org apart from source org). When I send user to authenticate himself into target org using url -https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize? (Providing Client Id, redirect uri, response type=code)user is automatically getting authenticated into source org and getting Allow or Deny page. How do I take user to goto login page without getting one redirected?

Comment: instance URL would be helpful to distinguish in this case.

Comment: But I cannot do that since logged in user could login to any salesforce org

Comment: But it would be difficult to control browser's behavior in this case. If you workbench also, it behaves the same way. May be you can have an intermediary page, which will ask about the instance URL and then you can forward it to that org.

Comment: Good point. I am expecting behavior where salesforce takes us to login.salesforce.com page instead of home page when user is already logged in.